# Find unknown coordinates of two vectors

Tags: geometry

I have a question today about vectors: suppose we are  asked find unknown $x$ coordinates of two vectors which are  directed opposite  sides, so  for example  one vector $a$  is vector   such that
   $a=(x,3)$   and second vector $b=(8,x)$  our task is to find $x$  please help me, I have a national exam in one week and meet such problem in the exam textbook.  Please give me idea how to solve such vector related problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Directed opposite sides means that there exists $k$ such that $ka=b$ and $k<0$. You get the equations $kx=8; 3k=x$. From here, find $k$ and pick the negative solution. From there, find $x$.